# text not showing in table view cell unless cell touched

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have table view set up in the traditional Master/Detail way in an iPhone app. When I click save on the detail screen (after adding the information I want), it switches back to the master list, however, the text that's supposed to appear in the cell in the Master list doesn't appear until I touch the cell with my finger, however, if I touch the cell with my finger it obviously segues to the detail screen and then I have to click "back" to get to the Master list where the cell now has the text that it's supposed to. Interestingly, the table view image is appearing immediately upon save - I don't have to touch the cell to make the image appear in the same way I have to make the text appear.

Clicking the "save" button in the detail screen runs this code. The `mnemonicField.text` gets saved to the currentTopic and I later set it to be the text that appears in the cell

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
    [self.currentTopic setTopic:topicField.text];
    [self.currentTopic setMnemonic:mnemonicField.text]; //this should appear in cell on master
    [self.currentTopic setMood: self.mood]; 
    [self.delegate AddTopicViewControllerDidSave];
}
```

The Master table view controller is the delegate referred to in the above method. Here is that method.

```
-(void)AddTopicViewControllerDidSave{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"saving topick");
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (![context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I call another method to setup the cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TopicCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

     [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];//sets up cell, see below

    return cell;

}
```

Here's `configureCell:atIndexPath` which sets up the cell. Again, note that both the image and the textLabel.text are set in this method but that I have to touch the cell with my finger to actually make the text appear

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell...
    Topic *topic = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = topic.mnemonic;
    NSLog(@"jokemood  in configure cell %@", joke.mood);
    UIImage *funnyimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nslaugh.png"];
    UIImage *badimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nsbad.png"];
    UIImage *crapimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nscrap.png"];
    UIImage *mehimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nsmeh.png"];
    UIImage *smileimage = [UIImage imageNamed: @"nssmile.png"];

    switch ([topic.mood intValue]) {
        case 0:
            // do something
            NSLog(@" topic table 0");

            cell.imageView.image = crapimage  ;
            break;
        case 1:
```

After some experimentation, I determined that the problem is this line `cell.textLabel.text = topic.mnemonic;` in the above function. If I take that line out, then the title shows in the cell in the master list immediately upon saving in the detail screen. However, if I take that line out, then when i start the application, the title is not getting assigned when the data's pulled from core data. So, either way there's a problem. If this line `cell.textLabel.text = topic.mnemonic;` is left in the above function, then I have to touch the cell in the master list (after saving in the detail) for the text to appear, but if I take that line out then the textLabel.text is not getting assigned when the application pulls from core data. Neither option is acceptable.

Do you know why this might be happening?

For the sake of completion here's prepareForSegue in the master view controller where I setup the currentTopic on the destination view controller based on the topic in the master view controller

```
 if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"AddJoke"]){

        MMAddTopicViewController *ajvc = (MMAddTopicViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        ajvc.delegate = self;
        ajvc.mood = nil;

        Topic *newTopic = (Topic *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Topic" inManagedObjectContext: [self managedObjectContext]];
        NSMutableSet* relationship = [self.rootObject mutableSetValueForKey:@"subItems"];

        NSManagedObject *lastObject = [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects lastObject];
        double lastObjectDisplayOrder = [[lastObject valueForKey:@"displayOrder"] doubleValue];


        [newTopic setValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:lastObjectDisplayOrder + 1.0] forKey:@"displayOrder"];
         [relationship addObject:newJoke];
        ajvc.currentTopic = newTopic;  ///currentTopic in destination view controller is set to topic from master view controller
```

Comment: If anyone's interested in this problem, I can send you a bare bones zipped file of the application via email

Answer (score 0):

I added `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the save method in the master view controller, which is called from the detail controller (master serves as the detail's delegate). The Lynda.com tutorial I copied it from didn't have to use `self.tableView reloadData`, not sure why my code did.

```
-(void)AddTopicViewControllerDidSave{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSLog(@"saving cock");
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (![context save:&error]){
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];


}
```